# Conditionally render routes in createBottomTabNavigator react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements, react-navigation

In my react-native application I want to conditionally render routes in my navigation menu. I use react-navigations `createBottomTabNavigator` for my navigation menu.

The condition is based on a users role and is retrieved through an api-call.

The api-call does not happen on initial load-up.

I am using `mobx-state-tree` for application state management, the role is stored in a MST store.

I have to decorate the top-level container `createAppContainer` with `observer` expecting a re-render when the observed role is changing. It seems inefficient to re-render at top-level and I could not make it to work anyway.

It is not possible to pass down props down through the HOC provided by `react-navigation` as far as I am concerned. And I cannot wrap them in components for achieving this, since they are used as arguments for the HOC's.

For some structural clarification I am using the following HOC's

- `createAppContainer` for wrapping my app. I pass it a
- `createSwitchNavigator` and pass it a
- `createBottomTabNavigator` that gets passed multiple
- `createStackNavigator` that gets passed the actual screens. These are the ones that needs to be conditionally rendered.

```js
//how can I at this level conditionally render 
function screenExcluder() {
    const stacks = {
        SomeStackNavigator,
        //...
    }
    console.log("MainTabNavigator, profilestore ", )

    if (UserStore.isRegularUser){
        stacks.ProfileStack = ProfileStack
        stacks.SettingsStack = SettingsStack
    }

    return stacks
}

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
    screenExcluder(), {
    tabBarComponent: Tabs,
})
```

I expect a solution to make `createBottomTabNavigator` conditionally render routes based on values based on changing values in a `mobx-state-tree` store

I am using react-navigation version 3.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin doesn't allow dynamic routes at the moment.

https://react-navigation.canny.io/feature-requests/p/dynamic-routes-for-navigators

You have to define all routes when the app is starting up. you can look for an alternative plugin like [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/quick-start)

for more options join this [thread](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3591)

**Suggession**

or you can change the way you plan your route security like rendering all the routes and securing them based on user

more info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html